# How do you totally reset a barman backup setup?

Tags: postgresql, barman

I have recently had a database crash and recovered the machine using methods other than barman in this case.

Now I have barman correctly annoyed about the status of the wal files, but for the life of me I can't work out how to reset things.

I tried the obvious

```
 barman rebuild-xlogdb db
Rebuilding xlogdb for server db
Done rebuilding xlogdb for server db (history: 0, backup_labels: 4, wal_file: 3027)
barman@dbqlbackup:/home/pnunn$ barman receive-wal --reset db
ERROR: The receive-wal position is ahead of PostgreSQL current WAL lsn (00000001000000A30000007A.partial > 000000010000009D00000096)
barman@dbsqlbackup:/home/pnunn$ barman receive-wal --stop db
ERROR: Termination of receive-wal failed: no such process for server db
```

When I run barman check db I get

```
Server db:
        PostgreSQL: OK
        superuser or standard user with backup privileges: OK
        PostgreSQL streaming: OK
        wal_level: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 3 backups, expected at least 0)
        ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
        systemid coherence: OK
        pg_receivexlog: OK
        pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
        receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: OK
        continuous archiving: OK
        archiver errors: FAILED (duplicates: 283)
```

Barman is correctly grumpy about having WAL files chopped off and resent and I'm happy to just blow away the current backups and WALS and start again from now (if that makes sense), but I can't for the life of me work out how.

I have tried rebuilding the xlogdb, tried to move the data directory, but couldn't because its in use.

Ive tried barman switch-wal --force --archive db but got a bunch of lines

```
 Error: 000000010000009D0000009F is already present in server db. File moved to errors directory.
    000000010000009D000000A0
    Error: 000000010000009D000000A0 is already present in server db. File moved to errors directory.
    000000010000009D000000A1
    Error: 000000010000009D000000A1 is already present in server db. File moved to errors directory.
    000000010000009D000000A2
    Error: 000000010000009D000000A2 is already present in server db. File moved to errors directory.
    000000010000009D000000A3
    Error: 000000010000009D000000A3 is already present in server db. File moved to errors directory.
```

But so far no joy.

I tried moving the /data directory to /data.old to start again, but it keeps telling me the directory is in use (even though lsof shows nothing).

Is there a "restart from scratch" command that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you had any luck re-sending the initial wal file from the source server?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I have not. I did get some advice from the mail list about increasing the size of the wal files, but as yet I've not had time to look at it, and will do that some time soon and see what happens. At the moment all of the backup machines are complaining about the file not being available.  I'll update here if I get anything better working.